# Vue.js. TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined even though vue-resource is definitely installed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

Okay, so:

1. I am getting a TypeError and I don't know why,
2. Vue-resource is installed, and imported `Vue.use('vue-resource');` `import {} from 'vue-resource';` in my main.js.

I have tried importing it different way, I have looked for a solution, with no luck.

The place I am invoking that function is after I click a button 
`<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="submit()">Submit</button>`.

The "submit" function looks like this:

````
      this.$http
        .post("https://vue-http-20bf2.firebaseio.com/data.json", this.user)
        .then(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    }```
````

Comment: I don't think you use it correctly https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/config.md#webpackbrowserify

Comment: try `Vue.http` instead of `this.$http `

Comment: @G.aziz tried it, didn't work. 

What I get is (weirdly) ```vue.js?3de6:1897 ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at VueComponent.submit (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1003), ```

Comment: And yes, I have Vue imported, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved it.

The issue was I don't know where. I had to basically import Vue and VueResource again, and tell Vue to use the package (again).

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import App from './App.vue'

`Vue.use(VueResource);`
```

Please note I already tried doing it that way.

In App.vue, I have

```
submit() {
      this.$http
        .post("https://vue-http-20bf2.firebaseio.com/data.json", this.user)
        .then(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    }
```